# Selenium errors

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to get the list of company names from : https://www.ces.tech/Exhibits/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx

How can I fix this error?
[image]

Thank you in advance.

I tried
SELECTOR
XPATH
and TAG_NAME('a') Print('company-name')

[image]

Comment: call the [API](https://www.ces.tech/api/Exhibitors?searchTerm=&sortBy=alpha&alpha=&state=&country=&venue=&exhibitorType=&pageNo=1&pageSize=30) directly ?

Comment: When I load that URL into my browser, it takes a few seconds before the list of company names are displayed. You might need to implement a wait feature, to allow the page to load completely.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0',
    'ctaapi-version': '1.1'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        params = {
            "alpha": "",
            "country": "",
            "exhibitorType": "",
            "pageNo": "1",
            "pageSize": "30",
            "searchTerm": "",
            "sortBy": "alpha",
            "state": "",
            "venue": ""
        }
        r = req.get(
            'https://www.ces.tech/api/Exhibitors', params=params)
        print(r.json())


main('https://www.ces.tech/Exhibits/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you have highlighted is what you want, I think the XPath would be something like:

```
names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h3[@class="company-name"]//a')
```

This would save all of the matching elements in the names variable. Then if there are multiple of these and you are trying to get the text then you could loop through them like this:

```
for i in names:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that gets all the company names into a list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.ces.tech/Exhibits/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx')
last_letter = 'A'
while last_letter < 'Z':
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    last_letter = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'followMeBar__content')[-1].text
company_names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'company-name')
names_list = []
for name in company_names:
    if name.text:
        names_list.append(name.text)
print(names_list)
print('Total count of name si', len(names_list))

driver.quit()
```

The page uses `lazy load` and it loads the next portion of names after each scroll so I created a loop that scrolls until company names starting from "z" appear on the page.
The code needs improvements. But it's enough to understand how to work with this page generally.